# How to use environment variables in Jenkins git plugin configuration

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I've got a job that checks out code from git. I'm using the [Pre-scm build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) plugin to run a simple batch script that creates a variable `BRANCH_NAME`. I am trying to configure the git plugin to check out to a sub-directory with the value of `BRANCH_NAME`.

I know I can use Jenkins job parameters or job information using `${VARNAME}` but it seems that this particular text box does not parse those.

Comment: See also: [Bug 23477](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23477) and [Bug 27508](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the “Check out to a subdirectory” option does not support variables, you could use a fixed name, like “x”. Then your first build step could execute:

```
mv x $GIT_BRANCH
```

Note that `$GIT_BRANCH` contains name of the Git remote and branch, like “origin/master”, so possibly you would want:

```
mv x $(basename $GIT_BRANCH)
```

Comment: Moving to a directory named after the git branch? How likely will this work? I think (hope) his `BRANCH_NAME` has nothing to do with `GIT_BRANCH`.